index.html generated by htmlwebpackplugin was not included in __WB_MANIFEST by WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest plugin
I am adding my configuration here.
webpack.prod.js:
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

const { PUBLIC_DIR, DIST_DIR } = require('./paths');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundles/[name].[contenthash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'bundles/[name].[contenthash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'maps/[name].[contenthash].map.js',
    publicPath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`,
  },
  optimization: {
    sideEffects: true,
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
        exclude: /\.map\.js$/,
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false,
          },
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        utilityVendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](lodash|lodash-es|formik)[\\/]/,
          name: 'utilityVendor',
        },
        baseVendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom|styled-components)[\\/]/,
          name: 'baseVendor',
        },
        default: {
          name: 'common',
          minChunks: 3,
          enforce: true,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: '[path][query].gz',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /\.map.js$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: `${PUBLIC_DIR}/icons`, to: 'icons/' },
        `${PUBLIC_DIR}/manifest.json`,
        `${PUBLIC_DIR}/newRelicScript.js`,
      ],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: `${DIST_DIR}/index.html`,
      template: `${PUBLIC_DIR}/index.html`,
      chunksSortMode: 'none',
      baseUrl: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`,
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
      resourceRegExp: /^redux-logger$/,
    }),
    new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
      swDest: 'serviceWorker.js',
      swSrc: './src/service-worker-custom.js',
      exclude: [/\.map.js$/],
      include: [
        /\.js$/,
        /\.css$/,
        /\.woff$/,
        /\.woff2$/,
        /\.gif$/,
        /\.svg$/,
        /\.png$/,
        /\.jpg$/,
        /\.html$/,
      ],
    }),
  ],
});


webpack.common.js
require('dotenv').config();
const webpack = require('webpack');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
var PACKAGE = require('../package.json');
const PATHS = require('./paths');
const envConfig = require('./envConfig');
// Set Environment
const ENV = process.env.APP_ENV || 'staging';
const Config = envConfig[ENV];
console.log(JSON.stringify(Config));
module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    app: `${PATHS.SRC_DIR}/index.js`,
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.DIST_DIR,
    filename: 'bundles/[name].[contenthash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'maps/[name].[contenthash].map.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: PATHS.SRC_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '[path][name].[contenthash][ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '[path][name].[contenthash][ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      App: PATHS.App,
      Components: PATHS.Components,
      Utilities: PATHS.Utilities,
      Services: PATHS.Services,
      constants: PATHS.Constants,
      State: PATHS.State,
      Pages: PATHS.Pages,
      Hooks: PATHS.Hooks,
      Locale: PATHS.Locale,
      LibraryComponents: PATHS.LibraryComponents,
      Redux: PATHS.Redux,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin({
      shorthands: true,
      collections: true,
      paths: true,
      caching: true,
      flattening: true,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(PACKAGE.version),
      ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV),
      PUBLIC_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.PUBLIC_URL),
      API: JSON.stringify(Config.apiUrl),
      GOOGLE_API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY),
      FIREBASE: JSON.stringify(Config.firebase),
      FIREBASE_API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY),
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
};

index.html was not included in the __WB_MANIFEST array.
while precaching in service worker using manifest index.html was not included. due to which offline experiences is being affected.
I had to do manual caching for index.html file and handling the updates.
I have attached my complete webpack configuration.
